# How draw(_ rect: CGRect) actually work?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview, uicolor

I don't understand how this function actually work
If I want to change Background Color of the "View" I will go to acces background property of the View and change value of it

```
let containerView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```

But When I want to change color of the rectangle in draw() function
I just call UIColor.green.set() function. Why this function change Color of the Rectangle

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)


        let rect = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 100, height: 100), cornerRadius: 5.0)
        UIColor.green.set()  // <- Why this line change rect color ?
        rect.fill()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,  @Moritz 
Sorry I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: Much better now. Please continue to improve it. Good luck! :)

Comment: Vey appreciate Thank you @Moritz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `UIView` has a `.backgroundColor` property. When UIKit wants to display the view, it checks the `.backgroundColor` property and "fills" the background with that color.

`UIColor.green.set()` and `rect.fill()` does not ***change*** the background color of the view.

When you override the `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` function, UIKit has already done its processing of `.backgroundColor` property, and filled the background as necessary. ***Your*** code then "draws a filled rectangle" on the background.

Comment: Thank you @DonMag
I have some little question
"UIColor.green.set()" is just a function. I don't understand Why this function can change Rect Color ?

Comment: It doesn't change the Rect Color... it "sets" the color to be used by the `fill()` function.

Comment: oh ok I understand it now Thank you @DonMag

Comment: Also `UIColor.set` is not so trivial. It actually gets the current context using `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` and then it sets both stroke and fill color on it. `rect.fill` also uses current context. The context is set by the drawing system before the `draw` method is called. Maybe it would be educational to rewrite the code using `context` operations.

Comment: Sulthan's comment here is useful. The confusion is arising because it looks like the `UIColor`'s "set" is unrelated to the rect's fill method. But what's happening is that both behind the scenes are working on an underlying stateful CoreGraphics context. If you dig deeper into CoreGraphics, you'll understand the mapping. I agree that it's counterintuitive if you're not familiar with more traditional stateful graphics contexts.